# How to decrease Nitrogen gas consumption in Iron & Steel Plant?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, compressed-air, compressors

I need to decrease nitrogen gas consumption in iron & steel plant.
Currently it's not possible to measure every dot from steel mill to determine real usage so they use what air separation unit sent (m3/h)..

There are some ways to do it:

- Using air compressors instead of nitrogen lines in steel mill and blast furnace
- Using air compressors for pneumatic & dust cleaner filters etc...

But what other ways? How to do it?

Comment: It sounds unusual for a steel plant to use this much nitrogen.

Comment: @user3528438 and how much is that?

Comment: @user3528438 why? nitrogen is useful for filters & slag splashing & dust cleaning etc. but it shouldn't require too much, so there must be ways to decrease consumption.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Right now it looks like you are only asking for a list of ideas. If you supplied more information, someone could help you actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have been in 100 steel mills and never noticed a nitrogen system. However it seems they could use inert gas blasting somewhere. And nitrogen would be so cheap and convenient because steel mills will generally have a cryogenic oxygen plant. Generally they are off site and may be owned by someone like Linde. Very simple to lay a nitrogen pipe next to the oxygen pipe and provide "free" nitrogen that would otherwise be vented into the atmosphere.